# AWS Amplify: Same admin query on two separate apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So here's my situation...I have two React apps that need to talk to the same Cognito User Pool. I've been able to accomplish this by copying the aws-exports.js file from the first app to the second app I created (not sure if this is something I should be doing or not but it is working). The issue I am having however is when I run an Admin Query on the second app (to say list users in the Cognito User Pool) I get a 403 (Forbidden) error. Has anyone ever run into this before? Googling all day has not helped me so I figured I would ask.

Comment: Its the same admin query, but is it the same Admin user in App2, that is making the query and getting the 403, as App1 that is making the query successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need "multi-frontend" solution:
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend

**I'll give you some useful infos for this:**

1. Open the Amplify Console and there the "first" app (wheres the backend was created).
2. Go to the first app's "backend" section
3. Select "Backend environments" tab
4. Search for "Edit backend" box and this text: "To continue working on the backend, install the Amplify CLI and make updates by running the command below from the root of your project folder"
5. copy that command, and paste/run in second app's root.

**Beware!**

1. do not modify (and push) the backend from the second application.
2. if you use git branch based environment you must always switch the env AND the branch parallel. Do not pull the "master" backend for your "dev" env.
3. try to avoid modifing on amplify console if you modify things with amplify cli. Those things cannot be syncronized... :(

If you store multiple apps in a git monorepo:
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/monorepo